# Function Composition Error

Tags: f#, functional-programming, function-composition

While going through a tutorial on Function Composition, I tried the following:

```
let prefixFun a b = a + "" + b;;
let exclaim s = s + "!";;
let bigHello = prefixFun >> exclaim;;
```

But the definition for `bigHello` returns the following type mismatch error

```
let bigHello = prefixFun >> exclaim;;
----------------------------^^^^^^^

stdin(28,29): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
'(string -> string) -> 'a'
but given a
    'string -> string'
The type 'string -> string' does not match the type 'string'
```

1. What does the error mean
2. As per my understanding, function composition requires return type of first function to be the same as parameter of the second, which I think is true here, since `prefixFun` returns string and `exclaim` expects string.

Could you help me understand and resolve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prefixFun`, after applying *one* argument, does not return a string. It returns a function, with type `string -> string` due to partial application and function currying.

This is the implementation of `>>`:

`let (>>) f g x = g ( f(x) )`

Note that `f` is applied to only one argument.

I have a feeling that what you want for `bigHello` is a function that takes someone's name and adds an exclamation mark afterwards. Here's what you can do with what you have!

`let bigHello = prefixFun "Hello " >> exclaim`

Note that `prefixFun "Hello "` has type `string -> string`,
so the rules for function composition are obeyed.